# Directory "not found" on HP-UX for NFS mount point

Tags: permissions, nfs, hp-ux

On an HP-UX B.11.31 that mount via NFS a remote disk using mount point `/BK_RESTORE`, I would like to access a sub directory with `oracle` user, but I cannot even if permissions are correct. Using a different normal user, like `bsp` works as expected.

(from root)

```
root> ls -ld / /BK_RESTORE /BK_RESTORE/erpln /BK_RESTORE/erpln/import-su-macchina-di-test
drwxr-xr-x  41 root       root          8192 Jul  8 09:43 /
drwxrwxrwx   2 root       sys         131072 Jul  8 10:06 /BK_RESTORE
drwxrwxrwx   2 root       sys         131072 Jul  8 09:44 /BK_RESTORE/erpln
drwxrwxrwx   2 root       sys         131072 Jul  8 10:05 /BK_RESTORE/erpln/import-su-macchina-di-test
```

(from bsp)

```
bsp> ls -ld / /BK_RESTORE /BK_RESTORE/erpln /BK_RESTORE/erpln/import-su-macchina-di-test
drwxr-xr-x  41 root       root          8192 Jul  8 09:43 /
drwxrwxrwx   2 bsp        bsp         131072 Jul  8 10:20 /BK_RESTORE
drwxrwxrwx   2 bsp        bsp         131072 Jul  8 09:44 /BK_RESTORE/erpln
drwxrwxrwx   2 bsp        bsp         131072 Jul  8 10:05 /BK_RESTORE/erpln/import-su-macchina-di-test
```

(from oracle)

```
oracle> ls -ld / /BK_RESTORE /BK_RESTORE/erpln /BK_RESTORE/erpln/import-su-macchina-di-test
/BK_RESTORE not found
/BK_RESTORE/erpln not found
/BK_RESTORE/erpln/import-su-macchina-di-test not found
drwxr-xr-x  41 root       root          8192 Jul  8 09:43 /
```

Please note that oracle lists the mount point with `ls /` but not with `ls -l /` (without giving any error).

Moreover, when changing to this directory from oracle user, I get this error:

```
cd /BK_RESTORE
sh: /BK_RESTORE: Permission denied.
```

Do you have an idea on what is happening?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems that HP-UX tricked me: while `mount` show the file system as NFS, it was really a CIFS one. And, since no username and password were provided when mounting it, authentication is done via `cifslogin` command. Probably this command was already issued for `root` and `bsp` users, while it was never issue for `oracle` user.
Please note that `cifslogin` credential are stored in a `cifsdb` database. I think that on this server all credentials were stored years ago, and now everyone here was completely unaware of this mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of the underlying directory used to mount the /BK_RESTORE filesystem.

i.e. unmount /BK_RESTORE and then check the permissions of the /BK_RESTORE directory.

You may find the underlying permissions are more restrictive, and in some situations, that can impact access in ways you might not expect.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Permissions for underlying directory are ok. I also discovered, while umounting and mounting it back, that the share is not NFS but CIFS. the `mount` command display it as NFS, still.